# Remove Duplicate from Nested List Python - Error

Tags: python, list, nested, duplicates

I have the following nested list:

```py
parameterList = [[0, -40, 0.001, 'No Ageing'], [0, -35, 0.001, 'No Ageing'], [0, -40, 0.001, 'No Ageing']]
```

I am trying to set-up a script to remove the duplicates within the nested list:

```py
res = list(set(map(lambda i: tuple(sorted(i)), parameterList))) 
# print result 
print("The list after duplicate removal : " + str(res))
```

Same with:

```py
res = list(set(tuple(sorted(sub)) for sub in parameterList))
```

But I get the error: `<` not supported between instances of `str` and `int`

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: What is the purpose of sorted()? I don’t think it’s needed.

Comment: But the sorted() is not applied to the whole collection, it’s applied to each list.

Comment: Your list contains members of different types, which makes it very difficult to compare. Is 0 (an integer) less than "hello" (a string)? The question doesn't make sense. That's what you're being told in that error message. You could convert everything into a string, or you could try removing sorted as others suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting your error because your list has both integers and strings ("No ageing")
When you call sorted(), it uses the < operator to sort your data, which then calls an error when your string pops up

I recommend making your own sorting function in that case; one which can add your string in whichever position you want.